# WordPress Registration Separate From User Registration

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to know if there is a plugin available or a way to achieve a registration process for a WordPress site that would be completely separate from thee site's users that can see the backend.  To clarify a bit, we want to have two registrations available, one for site admins or editors that have access to the actual WordPress backend, and one for additional clients that don't have access to the WordPress backend and do not share the same user database table.  We would not want them to even be listed as "Users" in the WordPress backend.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Why is that necessary? If someone is registered as a subscriber, he/she cannot do anything in the backend.

Comment: I fully understand that subscribers can't do anything unless they are given appropriate permissions.  What we're after is a completely separate registration from the WordPress users.  We don't even want them to be able to see the backend at all.  We need a registration process that a client can register to for other purposes than what the site user registration is used for.  I know this could be built fully custom with a form that submits to a new database table, but I was hoping for a piece of software already built.  I'll keep looking, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate system which uses OpenID. It's easiest

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your dashboard and check that the default [user role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) is set to subscriber. Subscribers only role is to read posts, they don't have access to the dashboard.